# Count Numbers of Argument in Function

Tags: asp.net, function, count, arguments

there are three arguments are passing in function,
but i want to dynamically count the numbers of arguments.

```
public List<ccBillDataObject> GetBill(string BranchID, string FromDate, string ToDate)
    {
        List<ccBillDataObject> BillList = new List<ccBillDataObject>();
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "spGetBill";
        DateTime dteFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate);
        DateTime dteToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intBranchID", BranchID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dteFromDate", dteFromDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dteToDate", dteToDate);
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dt = new DataTable();
    }
```

Comment: One way to do this would be to supply the arguments as a list, which can vary in length. You would then pick each argument from the list, rather than having them as separate parameters.

Comment: Ohkk, Let me try it out, and thanks :) @Jonatan

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a class for this Function. But if you really don't want to, you could use dynamics:

```
public List<ccBillDataObject> GetBill (IEnumerable<dynamic> list)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in list)
    {
        string name = item.Name;
        int id = item.Id;
    }
}
```

Note that this is not strongly typed, so if, for example, Name changes to EmployeeName, you won't know there's a problem until runtime.